# Spark: Use Temporary Table Twice in Query?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am working on converting a set of Hive queries to run on spark. So far I have gotten a nice performance boost by creating TEMP tables, where Hive was previously creating new tables on disc. I have run into a query where the TEMP table is being called twice in the same query and these causes a failure. I have tried to write my temp table to disc, but I notice that the "saveAsTable" function is deprecated, and when I try to use it my program fails due to executor timeouts. I would prefer to not have to write to disc anyway. I have considered rewriting the hive query, but would prefer to leave it alone. Do I have any other options?

Sample Query

```
SELECT d.LEVEL_1,
       d.LEVEL_2,
       d.CODE
           FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT CP.LEVEL_1_ID,
                    LEVEL_2_ID,
   FROM ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 CP
LEFT JOIN ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 F ON D.demo_id = F.demo_id
AND D.LEVEL_1_ID = F.LEVEL_1_ID
AND D.LEVEL_2_ID = F.LEVEL_2_ID
```

I have reduced the query a bit to try and show the basic concept, but may have broken it during reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has multiple parts. Did you try running -

first

```
SELECT CP.LEVEL_1_ID,
                    LEVEL_2_ID,
   FROM ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 CP
LEFT JOIN ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 F ON D.demo_id = F.demo_id
AND D.LEVEL_1_ID = F.LEVEL_1_ID
AND D.LEVEL_2_ID = F.LEVEL_2_ID
```

second

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.LEVEL_1_ID,
                    LEVEL_2_ID,
   FROM ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 CP
LEFT JOIN ETL_ESTIMATED_PROVIDER_DATA_1_1 F ON D.demo_id = F.demo_id
AND D.LEVEL_1_ID = F.LEVEL_1_ID
AND D.LEVEL_2_ID = F.LEVEL_2_ID
```

Also, the second one is your answer. You need not to do another select on top of that. You are missing in second select `d.CODE`.

I have ran similar self-joins in spark and it works.